# Пропала возможность добавлять точки останова в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

[image: Панель слева]

На панели слева больше нет возможности поставить точку останова

Answer (score 0):

Решение следующее:
Средства -> Параметры -> Текстовый Редактор -> Общие -> Экран -> Поле Индикаторов должно быть включено